# Can camel context be started automatically on EAP

Tags: jbossfuse

Ｉam using jboss fuse63 on eap6.4, to make camel context defined with spring DSL run after deploying the camel app as war, I have to use a listener class in web.xml, and use the listener class to start camel context as the following:

```
    ApplicationContext contextCommon = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("camel-context-common.xml");
    DefaultCamelContext camelContextCommon = (DefaultCamelContext)contextCommon.getBean("_camelContext_common");
    try {       
        camelContextCommon.start();
        ...
```

The abstract of my spring DSL is as the following(autoStartup="true" is defined):

```
<beans ...">
    <bean class="test.CommonProcessor" id="commProcessor"/>
    <camelContext autoStartup="true" id="_camelContext_common"
        shutdownRunningTask="CompleteAllTasks" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
```

Is there a way to make camel context run automatically on eap without using java code to start it?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is easy way. You have to correctly name your Spring XML file which contains Camel route. The file [naming convention](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/deploying_into_a_web_server/ch02s03#idm140226279844224) requires to include the `-camel-context.xml` suffix.

In your case, rename `camel-context-common.xml` file to `common-camel-context.xml`. If you do that then Camel subsystem will automatically start up camel contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a great way to do this.  Use the Wildfly-Camel subsystem and the very handy quickstarts for examples.
If you are using productised versions, you can use Fuse/EAP for this.
Good Luck,
Rick

Comment: Thanks Rick, this should be the answer for community version, but my client need to run camel on redhat version, that is fuse6.3 on jboss eap 6.4, which brings me 2 concerns:1) Does redhat support issues on wildfly-camel if I have subscription on fuse ? (I need official support rather than community support); 2) which EAP version is supported for wildfly-camel? the doc for wildfly-camel only show compatibility with wildfly which does not mapping to version of EAP.